# 11.04 server does not boot after installation

Tags: 11.04, server, lvm

Have successfully finished the re-installation of 11.04 server (single OS), but when I reboot the text "Linux Operating System ..." is displayed and then it stops. Previous test installation of 11.04 server on the same partitioning scheme booted properly. Any idea of what's going wrong?

I suspect that the reason is that the /boot/grub directory is missing on the / partition (LVM). Instead, it is located on the /boot partition.

In the Partiotion part I set the following manually (lvms already exist) 
/boot /dev/sda1/ (ext2, boot flag set)
/     vg_ubuntu-lv_root (ext4)
swap  vg_ubuntu-lv_swap (swap)
/tmp  vg_ubuntu-lv_tmp  (ext4)

In the end of the installation I select GRUB to be installed on the MBR partition since it's a single OS (have tried to place it on / but /dev/mapper/vg_ubuntu-lv_root does not work).

Br,
Johan

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you boot off the install CD in to a Live environment and then look up on Google how to reinstall grub to boot off of a LVM root partition.

When I have boot woes, some times I've found Super Grub Disk very helpful, though I think in your case it won't be able to help much.

Also, when really stuck, you may want to check for solutions in the Debian world.

And when stuck supremely, try the Gentoo documentation for hints.